# Why exactly binding a socket to multiple ports is not allowed?

Tags: sockets, port, bind

Why does this limitation exist? What is the technical reason for it?

AFAIU, ports were introduced to distinguish between facilities (services, connections, etc.) of the same host, so *logically* the limitation is reasonable. However, `SO_REUSEADDR` exists to allow one-port-to-many-sockets binding, but not the other way round. It seems practical, because it would spare a system call wasted on multiplexing; many SO questions seek (fruitlessly) a way to do it. But the lack of implementation suggests there are some obstacles I cannot figure.

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR doesn't let you reuse an address that already has an active listener bound to it when using AF_INET sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that UDP and TCP connections are keyed based on the IP-Port Pair.  This is how the stack figures out what goes with what internally.

If we had many ports to one it would require some other mechanism to key the connection so that the proper data would be delivered to the proper application thread/session.

Comment: They didn't specify which type of socket to use. It's possible to configure a raw IP socket to receive _all_ incoming packets and handle the connection yourself, but I doubt that's what the guy is asking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @David, but this does not explain the limitation. Why not add another record in (address, port)-to-socket mapping with the same socket? It would not impact performance worse than using two or more sockets. In Linux kernel, [there is a check](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/udp.c#L261) if a port is in use, but why is it required?

Comment: @chemdt I meant UDP sockets mostly. I am aware of raw sockets capabilities, however what I'm seeking is understanding of why sockets work the way they do.

Comment: This is simply how the standard was established back in the 70s.  The way the ports and ips are used naturally lead to them being used to key the connection.

Comment: Both now and then using (address, port) to key a system resource didn't require an explicit rule against binding to multiple endpoints.  As for the standards, I failed to find this restriction in RFC 768 (UDP).  I doubt there is a piece of OS networking stack which ruins a useful capability for no reason.

RFC 761 (TCP) states that "[Port] concatenated with the network and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a socket. A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection," which conflicts with binding to multiple ports *for TCP* (or connection-oriented protocols).

Comment: (address, port) is the most granular definition for a TCP/UDP connection. If you would like to multiplex then you are more than welcome to use multiple sockets. That's the way it is.

Comment: @chemdt,  1. My question is not related to a particular problem, in practice I'd use the API there is without a second thought.  2. I would like (hypothetically) quite the opposite---to receive packets on several ports (even probably endpoints) via a single socket disregarding what destination (i. e. local) address and port those packets had. But it is not allowed and I'm trying t understand *why*. If "That's the way it is" is a correct answer (i. e. the reasons are purely historical), it is a valid option.

Comment: Ah! You can do exactly what you want in your second point using raw sockets, but the catch is you'll have to filter on each packet  yourself and the data returned will include the layer 4 headers.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, @chemdt, and for suggesting solution. Unfortunately, I was rather interested in *why* does implementation explicitly deny this useful capability. Reading Linux kernel sources revealed that bind()'ing to multiple endpoints is restricted by implementation of a hashtable, but is possible logically (not that OS would allow that soon). So the answer pointed to the right direction.